# GAE redirection with a delay

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

Is that possible to redirect to another url with a delay in GAE? I know I can use JavaScript for this purpose, but may be there is a way to do delayed redirection without it?
Now I use `self.redirect("/")` from GAE tutorial.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x;url=http://yoururl/">` tag where x is the number of seconds to wait before redirect.
This tag would go in `<head>` part of the generated page.

Comment: I suppose it's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This is equivalent to setting an HTTP 'Refresh' header.

Answer (score 1):

`import time`  at the top of your module and do a `time.sleep(0.5)` before you do a self.redirect call. The sleep argument can take a floating point value of number of seconds to delay. Just make sure that you don't exceed 30 seconds of delay as GAE expects that every request be handled within that otherwise it will be interrupted.

Comment: Seems like it works not exactly as needed. For some reason it delays the whole page loading. I want to show some content like 'Now you will be redirected...' and then redirect after some delay.

Comment: Okay, I see you got your solution using meta tag. The Server Side way will execute till completion whenever a call is made. For what you would need, you might consider using javascript and then let the server handle the redirected page.