# Temporary page while redirect on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I want to create a temporary page where the browser lingers for a few seconds and is then redirected to another page. Working on python on Google App Engine. I thought the below should work(I am a total novice at this) but clearly it doesn't.

```
class TempPage(PageHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.response.write("You will be redirected to the Front page.")
                time.sleep(3)
                self.redirect('/')
```

PageHandler inherits from webapp2.RequestHandler.

Can someone please tell me what should be done.

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203378/gae-redirection-with-a-delay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want to use the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag. There are some examples on that page, but you basically add a tag that looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="TIME_TO_WAIT;URL='PAGE_TO_REDIRECT_TO'">
```

and put that in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Aaah! This was simpler than I thought. I should have googled more. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The browser only receives the page when all your code has executed. In your code that is after `self.redirect('/')` is executed as that's the last line of code in the handler. You probably don't even see the text `"You will be redirected to the Front page."`

So all that happens here is that your webpage takes 3 seconds to load and then redirects immediately.

You might want to try redirecting the user via javascript in the page that you send them.

A similar question is asked and answered here: [time delayed redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The meta refresh tag mentioned in another answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Point was really that although you can write multiple times to the response it's all sent "at once" to the browser once your code has executed, it's not incremental in any way.

Comment: Yes I did think so when it didn't work when I tried. Thanks for making it clear.