# how can i make a delay of 5 sec while redirecting one page to another in django views

Tags: python, django

I used this code but the delay I want is not accomplished . I want it to stay there for atleat 5 sec

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request) :
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")
```

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5203418/654952. Although I haven't tried yet, IMHO it'll work: setup a template for `myview`, get it rendered with the desired delays and redirect urls.

Comment: A you sure that this delay should be on server side? Will not this be a bad user experience?

Comment: No actually it would be a promotion page in between the user registering on site and being redirected to the shop products page .Let me see this delay if ts anoying i'll decrease it to 3 sec.

Comment: It should be on the client side. It's not about user experience, but server resources.

Comment: Yeah Right I used jQuery instead .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jquery settimeout function on the respective page, where you want stay for certain time say 5 sec.

For Example :

```
setTimeout(function() {
     $.get("{% url 'ABC' %}") // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

inside function you can put the code for redirect 'ABC' is the url name which you define in urls.py file

Answer (score 2):

just import time module in your views file and call sleep method and
pass the time

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import time

def myview(request) :
    time.sleep(5)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")
```

or you can just add this javascript snippets in your template file

```
 <script>
       setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'here pass the path';
         }, 5000);
   </script>
```