# How we can hold the user for a second for please wait msg in Django as we show in PHP with refresh tag?

Tags: python, php, django

How we can hold the user for a second for "please wait message"  after the login and signup procedure in Django as we show in PHP with refresh tag?

```py
return redirect('homePage')
```

Comment: Avoid the **PHP**  tag from your post. It has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: In PHP we use  header('refresh:2;url=index.php');  something like that so how we do this kind of thing in Django

Comment: Hello @UmairMustafa you can do ajax call for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i make a delay of 5 sec while redirecting one page to another in django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890899/how-can-i-make-a-delay-of-5-sec-while-redirecting-one-page-to-another-in-django)